# Minimization of an expression through K-map, in which there are more chances of errors and with Quine-McCluskey Method there are less chance of errors

Tags: boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

Minimization of any expression of **4 variables** through K-map, in which there are **more chances of errors** (like error in grouping) and the **same expression** with Quine-McCluskey Method there are **less chance of errors** *but it should be of 4 variables*. And I know that  Quine-McCluskey Method gives accurate result as compare to K-map, when the number of variables exceed from 4 but what about 4 variables?

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete... do you have a minimal example of what you are trying to do and what is going wrong?

Comment: If your question is abstract (about the strategies themselves) rather than concrete (a given implementation/coding of yours), then maybe you should ask in https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yes,  my question is abstract and to find the strategy to solve this type of questions. And trying to find the general solution.